# Showing only one category on portfolio page BUT filtering remaining categories with Isotope

Tags: custom-post-types

I have built an isotope portfolio Wordpress theme which so far is working perfectly:

Anything posted in the custom post type 'portfolio' shows on the homepage and is filterable by the 'portfolio-category' taxonomy using the Isotope JQuery plugin.

So far so good.

However, I wish to make a small improvement.

**I only want FEATURED portfolio items to show on the homepage.** For example, only portfolio items with the taxonomy classification of 'featured'. This part I have achieved easily with a custom query (see code snippet below).

The problem I am having is displaying the filterable buttons. I don't want a filterable button to say 'Featured' (defies the point), nor do I want any taxonomies to appear which aren't applicable to any of the featured items (because if clicked, *all* the portfolio items being displayed will disappear).

Here is my current query to show the portfolio items. No problems here:

```
<?php
// Query the portfolio posts 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'portfolio-category' => 'featured',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
?>
<!-- PORTFOLIO ITEM -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And here is the code I have currently which outputs the filterable taxonomies. This is what needs addressing.

```
<?php
    $terms = get_terms('portfolio-category');
    $count = count($terms);
    echo '<li class="filtering"><a href="#" title="" data-filter="*" class="button-primary">All</a></li>';
        if ( $count > 0 ){
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $termname = strtolower($term->name);
                $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
                echo '<li class="filtering"><a href="#" title="" data-filter=".'.$termname.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
?>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the terms from the current query. To achieve this you can use [`wp_get_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms), but it expects IDs, which we can extract by using [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) on the query objects `posts` property. It seems like you only need the names, which we can extract again with `wp_list_pluck()` from the result `wp_get_object_terms()` returns. Last but not least, the array returned might have duplicates, so we make it unique with `array_unique()`. In summary this would look somewhat along the lines of the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'          => 'portfolio',
    'portfolio-category' => 'featured',
    'posts_per_page'     => -1 
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

$loop_posts     = $loop->posts;
$loop_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $loop_posts, 'ID' );

$loop_term_objects          = wp_get_object_terms( $loop_posts_ids, 'portfolio-category' );
$loop_term_names_not_unique = wp_list_pluck( $loop_term_objects, 'name' );
$loop_term_names_unique     = array_unique( $loop_term_names_not_unique );
```

From there you can build your filter buttons for that specific query. Just remove the `featured` term from the array or skip the output for it in your `foreach` loop to not have it shown.

---

*Edit:*

Below some code for testing, or to be more exact, proof of concept for the method. It will return the term names on the post type `post` archive aka »Page for Posts« and single views of posts of the post type `post` - otherwise, on other pages, it returns empty. You can put this into your `functions.php` - you need PHP 5.3++, because of the anonymous function.

```
add_action( 'shutdown', function () {
    global $wp_query;
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach (
        array_unique(
            wp_list_pluck(
                wp_get_object_terms(
                    wp_list_pluck(
                        $wp_query->posts,
                        'ID'
                    ),
                    'category'
                ),
                'name'
            )
        ) as $term_name
    ) {
        print_r( $term_name . '<br>' );
    }
    echo '</pre>';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. My PHP is a little rusty but

`foreach ( $loop_term_names_unique as $term ) {
// ECHO SOMETHING WITH .$TERM.   
}`

Returns an error (the dreaded blank page)

Comment: The code I've posted works - I'm 99.99% certain. I'm guessing you have an other - non related - PHP syntax problem. You should enable debugging to get a hold of what the problem is. I'm adding some test-code for a proof of concept to the answer. @J-C

Answer (score 1):

@ialocin many many thanks. I have got it to work. Here is my full code based on yours:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'          => 'portfolio',
    'portfolio-category' => 'featured',
    'posts_per_page'     => -1 
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$loop_posts     = $loop->posts;
$loop_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $loop_posts, 'ID' );
$loop_term_objects          = wp_get_object_terms( $loop_posts_ids, 'portfolio-category' );
$loop_term_names_not_unique = wp_list_pluck( $loop_term_objects, 'name' );
$loop_term_names_unique     = array_unique( $loop_term_names_not_unique );

echo '<li class="filtering"><a href="#" title="" data-filter="*" class="button-primary">All</a></li>';

// start loop
            foreach ( $loop_term_names_unique as $term ) {
                $termfilter = strtolower($term);
                $termfilter = str_replace(' ', '-', $termfilter);
                echo '<li class="filtering"><a href="#" title="" data-filter=".'.$termfilter.'">'.$term.'</a></li>';
            }
// end loop  


?>
```

All I need to figure out now is removing "featured" from the array so that portfolio-category itself doesn't appear as a filterable item.

Huge thanks.

Comment: My pleasure! Put `if ( $term == 'featured' ) { continue; }` after the `foreach` line to skip in case of that term.

Comment: You the man! That did the trick, although it is case sensitive so have changed to *F*eatured (as that's how it is spelt in my taxonomy. Brilliant stuff! Many thanks.